# Javascript not working on content pulled from another source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty sure this is a dumb issue, but I searched and could not find a similar/equal scenario.

So, I have a main PHP page in which I include several Javascript files in the `head` section of the HTML. Then at some point I grab content (HTML + Javascript) from an outside source via `file_get_contents` and output it to the main page.

This new output will pick up the CSS styles from the main page normally, but any Javascript code that relies on the ones loaded at the main will not work. Even if I put the Javascript needed inside a `document.ready` in the main page, it will still not work.

Just to exemplify the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="somejslib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Some HTML here generated by PHP
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://whatever/page');
echo $content;
?>
</body>
```

In the grabbed content I will have something like:

```
<div>
<form>
<input type="text" id="bla">
</form>
</div>
<script>$('#bla').datepicker({ somecodehere });</script>
```

The `datepicker` was included in the libs loaded in the main page, but will not work, no matter where I put this code.

Any hints?

P.S: the only way it DOES work is if I include - again - all the Javascript libs inside the new content, which of course is not a solution.

Comment: you can use $window.load method .

Comment: Try $(document).ready(function(){ $('#bla').datepicker({ somecodehere }); });

Comment: try @Jitendra solution

Comment: user timeout function after the script running completed.

Comment: As already pointed out in the question: already tried `document.ready`, also `window.load`. And even putting these things in the MAIN document. Doesn't work.

Comment: Check in console for error's if any. And also load jquery.js file before any javascript..

Comment: All the needed files are loaded in the main page, jQuery also. The only error I get is "datepicker is not a function" - which basically means the new content is completely ignoring all previously loaded javascript.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. [This code](http://pastebin.com/A1pe2JTd) works for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. Just pasted this example code in new files, ran it locally, and it works. I don't know what is different, other than the fact, of course that it is a lot more code, a lot more libraries. But in theory it SHOULD work. :(

Answer (score 0):

make sure you attach the listeners after the external content is loaded or use the on() event handler
http://api.jquery.com/on/

P.S. I now see your code is actually missing the document.ready and thus not waiting for the document to be loaded before executing. I'm not sure which of these applies to your actual code as you only posted an example. If you pull the content in via an ajax for example apply the first solution otherwise just wrap things up in a document ready

Comment: Already tried document.ready, both within the new content and also on the main page. No go.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Apparently it was my mistake all along. I was loading Jquery multiple times (different versions, also).

It seems that not all versions of jQuery can take care of this situation.